# Java using regex to verify an input string

Tags: java, regex

g.:

```
String string="Marc Louie, Garduque Bautista";
```

I want to check if a string contains only words, a comma and spaces. i have tried to use regex and the closest I got is this :

```
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+(\\s[a-zA-Z]+)+";
```

but it doesnt check if there is a comma in there or not. Any suggestion ?

Comment: "a" comma, or commas?

Comment: What does a "word" mean to you? I see that your example has names, in which case "Skłodowska-Curie" would also be a "word" but it contains dash which is outside [a-zA-Z] range. There might be a couple of more such exceptional cases (eg. diacritics as in the example above).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use the pattern

```
^[A-Za-z, ]++$
```

For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String input = "Marc Louie, Garduque Bautista";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z, ]++$");
    if (!pattern.matcher(input).matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid String");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As per Michael's [astute comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005234/java-using-regex-to-verify-an-input-string/16005267#comment22824739_16005234) the OP might mean a single comma, in which case

```
^[A-Za-z ]++,[A-Za-z ]++$
```

Ought to work.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just simply:

```
"[a-zA-Z\\s,]+"
```

Comment: `\s` matches more than just spaces.

Comment: \s matches all spaces (e.g. tabs, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Use this will best

```
"(?i)[a-z,\\s]+"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "some words, any spaces and one single comma, wherever it occurs to be" then my feeling is to suggest this approach:

```
"^[^,]* *, *[^,]*$"
```

This means "Start with zero or more characters which are NOT (^) a comma, then you could find zero or more spaces, then a comma, then again zero or more spaces, then finally again zero or more characters which are NOT (^) a comma".

Answer (score -1):

To validate String in java where No special char at beginning and end but may have some special char in between.

```
String strRGEX = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9-/?:.,\'+_\\s])+([a-zA-Z0-9])$";
        String toBeTested= "TesADAD2-3t?S+s/fs:fds'f.324,ffs";
        boolean testResult= Pattern.matches(strRGEX, toBeTested);
        System.out.println("Test="+testResult);
```